# Input checkboxes with different values/names

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have one page website with form:
[Image from my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HUbv.jpg)

When user chose option 1, 2 or 3 and fill out form - then after pressing submit button, the data is entered into the database.

My database table structure:

```
ID | NAME | EMAIL | ADDRESS | CITY | ZIP | PRODUCT
```

There is no price row, because i cant figure out how to insert price value into checkbox.
After user pressing submit button, all the data is inserted in the database, everything is fine, but I can't find a solution to add a price to each product in input checkbox field.

This is my query for insert data:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (name, address, email, zip, city, product) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$product = $_POST['product'];

$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $address, $email, $zip, $city, $product);

$stmt->execute();

}
```

And this is my form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="form__form">
              <div class="form__body">
                <div class="form__desc">Wir liefern innerhalb von 24 Stunden. Mit 100% Geld Zurück Garantie
                </div>
                <div class="form__subtitle form__subtitle_top">Sofort lieferbar!
                </div>
                <div class="form__inputs">
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Vor-und Nachname" required="required" />
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Adresse" required="required" />
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Postleitzahl" required="required" />
                    <input class="form__input" type="text" name="city" placeholder="Stadt" required="required" />
                </div>
                
<div class="form__subtitle">Produkt</div>
                
                <div class="form__checks">
                  <label class="check"><input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product1" name="product1" checked="checked" /><span class="check__view"></span><span class="check__legend">1 Flasche, 60 Pillen für 150 €</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="check"><input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product2" name="product2" /><span class="check__view"></span><span class="check__legend">3 Flaschen, 180 Pillen für 300 €</span>
                  </label>
                  <label class="check"><input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product3" name="product3" /><span class="check__view"></span><span class="check__legend">6 Flaschen, 360 Pillen für 450 €</span>
                  </label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form__note">1 Monat nach der Erstlieferung erhalte ich monatlich im Abonnement 1 Flasche zu 149 €. Ich kann das Abonnement jederzeit kündigen.
                </div>

                <label class="one-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="one-check__input" />
                    <span class="one-check__view"></span>
                    <span class="one-check__legend">Ja, meine Angaben sind richtig und vollständig, ich akzeptiere die <a href="#" target="_blank">allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen</a></span>
                </label>

              </div>
              <div class="form__bottom">
                <div class="form__note form__note_bottom">Mit Klick auf „Kaufen“ bestellen Sie verbindlich.
                </div>
                <div class="form__group">
                  <button class="button button_full" type="submit" name="submit"><span>Kaufen</span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="form__guard">Pillen werden in einer anonymen und subtil- Paket gesendet. (Pills passen in die Mailbox)
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

My problem is that product 1, product 2 and product 3 - all 3 have their price.
Product 1 - 150EUR, Product 2 - 300EUR, Product 3 - 450EUR.
How can I add a price to the input (checkbox) fields? So I can create an invoice, because right now it only shows the product name, no price.

Comment: `value="Product1"` needs to be changed to `value="1 Flasche, 60 Pillen für 150 €"` --  Or whatever you want saved in the DB as price.  Could just be `value="150EUR"`  or `value=" Product 1 - 150EUR"` -- The point is that `value` is what is being sent through the `$_POST`

Comment: As Zak said, change your value="ProductX" to something else. Could be the quantity of bottles (1, 3, 6), or a product ID that your PHP either knows the price of, or can look up.

Comment: Also... if you want them to select one and only one (which is what your use of "radio" is implying...), you'll want the "name " value of each of those to match.

Answer (score 0):

According to your post:

*Product 1 - 150EUR, Product 2 - 300EUR, Product 3 - 450EUR. How can I add a price to the input (checkbox) fields?*

.. You need to change `value` in your `radio` buttons..

**ALSO** The `name` on your `radio` fields needs to be the same ..  I changed it to `product_check` -- It can be seen on the `php` side as `$_POST['product_check']`

```
<label class="check">
    <input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product 1 - 150EUR" name="product_check" checked="checked" />
    <span class="check__view"></span>
    <span class="check__legend">1 Flasche, 60 Pillen für 150 €</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
    <input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product 2 - 300EUR" name="product_check" />
    <span class="check__view"></span>
    <span class="check__legend">3 Flaschen, 180 Pillen für 300 €</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
    <input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product 3 - 450EUR" name="product_check" />
    <span class="check__view"></span>
    <span class="check__legend">6 Flaschen, 360 Pillen für 450 €</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Changed the name of the radio buttons so that the radio button deselects it's siblings when selecting itself, and added a simple jquery button to fetch the value of the currently selected one.

```js
function showProductValue() {
  console.log("Product: " + $("input[name=product]:checked").val());
}
```

```css
.check {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="check">
    <input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product1::150" name="product" checked="checked" />
    <span class="check__view"></span>
    <span class="check__legend">1 Flasche, 60 Pillen für 150 €</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
    <input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product2::300" name="product" />
    <span class="check__view"></span>
    <span class="check__legend">3 Flaschen, 180 Pillen für 300 €</span>
</label>
<label class="check">
    <input class="check__input" type="radio" value="Product3::450" name="product" />
    <span class="check__view"></span>
    <span class="check__legend">6 Flaschen, 360 Pillen für 450 €</span>
</label>
<button onClick="javascript:showProductValue();">Click Me</button>
```

```
/* Your POST variable will look something like:
$_POST = array(
    'name' => "Some Name",
    'address' => "Some Address",
    'email' => "Some Email",
    'zip' => "Zip Code",
    'city' => "City Name"
    'product' => "Product1::150"
);
*/
$product_arr = explode("::", $_POST['product']);
$product = $product_arr[0];  // "Product1"
$product_price = $product_arr[1]; // "150"
```

I added a delimiter ("::") to the "value" attribute of each radio button, then in your PHP you can explode based on that delimiter. I don't know how your products are stored in your database or if they are at all...? but this should make it so you have the price and the name in two separate variables and can do with them as you like (like inserting into the DB table?).

Comment: This seems good, but how value="300" will appear in the database under the price row?

Comment: So it'll appear in PHP as $_POST['product'] = "[150, 300, or 450]" as is in my code above, if you'd rather have it pass a product NAME or IDENTIFIER to the PHP, change the "value" attribute to what you want the $_POST['product'] to be. You'll then have to map that product to the price in your PHP, in... any number of ways of your choosing.

Comment: I think im stupid. I cant understand how value (price/300EUR) will be inserted into database, if there is name = product (and table row too).

Comment: Not stupid, learning, big difference. :) check out the answer again... I've edited it to include both product name and price and added the php section. Feel free to ask for clarification. Happy to help.

Comment: Maybe i just need to create different database table and make 3 records with my products and prices, and then somehow display them @ admin panel? I need this, because im gonna use dompdf as an invoice and i need price and product name, not - Product 1 - 300EUR, but in different rows @ database.

Comment: Yeah, a separate table to add products would work well. For example: products table could have "ID", "Name", and "Price". Then the table that you told us about in your original question could store the "ID" from the products table in the "product" column of that original table.

Comment: Okay, now i have table for products only.  ID, NAME, PRICE. And main table with: ID, customerName, customerEmail, customerAddress, customerCity, customerZip, customerOrder (orderedProduct). And what i need to do next?

Answer (score -1):

There are several errors in your code:

1- name of input type radio is product1..2..3 While you receive the value of the post for product:

```
$product = $_POST['product'];
```

so undefined index: product;

2- How can I add a price to the input (checkbox) fields? as you said,
Where is the fields you want to add price values to? It doesn't exist.

You need to assign a single price to the product, right?

So you need to create a table in the database and get product prices from it, then the html should be like this:

```
foreach ($resutls as result){echo'<input type="radio" name="product" value="'.$result->varofprice.'">';}
```